# Did Kishimoto kill Itachi because he was too strong to fight in the Fourth Great Ninja War?

Tags: naruto

I have seen many sites stating Kishimoto has said that if Itachi was alive during the Fourth Great Ninja War he would've easily defeated Madara and that is the reason why Kishimoto had him killed.

Can anyone point me to some sources for these comments?

Comment: You should probably include a few links to the sites in which you found those statements.

Comment: @JNat is correct. I've skimmed this http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:164031 but no real correlation with your statement.

Comment: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:163551    http://www.thetoptens.com/powerful-naruto-characters/uchiha-itachi-130993.asp  here are some links

Comment: I don't know why kishi stated like that...The So6p rinne sharingan madara was way more powerful than even the so6p naruto and sasuke combined.... we didn't get a chance see his powers, after all....

Comment: I need sources and links to believe that Itachi can kill a man that destroyed an army, awakened the rinnegan (which is stronger than the sharingan [chapter 373 pg 2]), awakened the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan, summoned meteors from space, wrecked the 5 kage with ease. Shall I continue? There's no way Itachi is stronger then the famed Madara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's true. While Itachi is powerful, he is no match for Madara Uchiha, who defeated the 5 kages himself. While Itachi's Susanoo contains the Totsuka blade and a nearly invincible shield, Madara has the perfect Susanoo, which makes it a league of its own.

Even so, Itachi did appear in the Fourth Shinobi War, and while he made Kabuto un-reanimate all the Edo Tenseis (including Itachi himself), Edo Tensei Madara was not stopped.

Comment: Itachi (though very sick) lost to sasuke as well. Even if he had lived, he would have only gotten weaker by the time of the war. The rumor is more sourced from the rumor that Itachi would have eventually become as strong as if not stronger than Madara due to how powerful he was while he was so young. He was an Anbu Capitain at 13, So he was a Top level jonin at the same age as Sasuke and Naruto were graduating from the acadamy.

Comment: He didn't lose to Sasuke, he planned it already and he has no intentions of killing Sasuke.

Comment: There is also the fact that the whole of Akatsuki didn't attack Konoha only because of Itachi. So i think we can assume that he was given that weird disease just to make sure that Itachi doesn't become the hero instead of Naruto